# Send email notification to follower

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I want to send an email notification to an user x when user y is starting to follow user x

I have the following method in my follows controller:

```
  class FollowsController < ApplicationController

  before_action :authenticate_user!

  def create
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
    if @user.present?
      current_user.follow!(@user)
   ModelMailer.new_follower_notification(@user).deliver
    end
  end

  def destroy
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
    if @user.present?
      follow = current_user.follows.get_follow(@user).first if current_user.follows
      if follow
        follow.destroy
      end
    end
    respond_to do |format|
      format.js { render :file => "/follows/create", :handlers => [:erb] }
    end
  end   
end
```

My modelmailer:

```
def new_follower_notification(user)
    @user = user
    mail to: user.email, subject: "#{@user.name}, you are now followd by others.", bcc: "oliviervanhees@gmail.com"
  end
```

In my view folder I have a create.js.erb file

```
<% if @user %>
  $('#user_<%= @user.id %>').html('<%= escape_javascript(render :partial => 'users/user', :locals => { :user => @user }) %>');
<% end %>
```

And this in my routes file:

```
  match '/users/:id/follow' => 'follows#create', :as => :user_follow, :via => [:post]
  match '/users/:id/unfollow' => 'follows#destroy', :as => :user_unfollow, :via => [:delete]
```

I try to trigger the model mailer, however I get errors by doing so. I think it is because I am using JSON here. Anyone any suggestions who to resolve this?

Comment: Please show the code where you are triggering the mailer and the code for the mailer itself.

Comment: I have added the code to the post. Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: Thanks. Now what is the error you are getting and where is it occurring?

Comment: The follow button is not working anymore, at least I have to reload the page to make it work. So the JSON is not working anymore

Comment: What JSON? I don't see any in the code you posted.

Comment: or Javascript (I am sorry I think I am mixing up some terms)??